# VBA Get Actual First Column When Using ADODB.Recordset

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file I'm querying with the following column headers:

JIRA #, BO Report Name, BO Report Location, Date Completed, Attempts

When using the below code, it returns column 5 (Attempts) as the first field. I know this is likely because the column header alphabetically starts first, but my question is how can I make it so the first record in the recordset is the first column, the second record in the recordset is the second column, and so on?

```
Sub GetHeaders()
'add Microsoft Scripting Runtime to your reference library

    Dim ado As Object
    Dim instanceFile As Object

    FilePath = "Your file path" '''Change

    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set instanceFile = GetObject(FilePath)

    With ado
        .Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & FilePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1""; Mode=Read;"
        With .OpenSchema(20)
            Dim table As String
            Dim rs As Object
            Dim vFieldName As String

            table = .Fields("TABLE_NAME")
            Set rs = ado.OpenSchema(4, Array(Empty, Empty, table))
            On Error Resume Next
            rs.MoveFirst
            On Error GoTo 0
            While Not rs.EOF
                Debug.Print rs!COLUMN_NAME
                rs.MoveNext
            Wend
        End With
    End With

    ado.Close
    instanceFile.Close
    Set instanceFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use `OpenSchema` rather than accessing the field names (column names) of the underlying table directly then you can make use of the "ORDINAL_POSITION" field. This is  part of the COLUMNS rowset which is returned by `ado.OpenSchema(4, Array(Empty, Empty, table))`

Here's a quick example of using "ORDINAL_POSITION" with a Dictionary to sort the field names. Replace everything in the original code between `On Error Resume Next` and the first `End With` with this code:

```
        rs.MoveFirst
        On Error GoTo 0
        Dim dictColumns As Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim i As Integer
        Set dictColumns = New Scripting.Dictionary

        While Not rs.EOF
            dictColumns.Add rs.Fields("ORDINAL_POSITION").Value, rs.Fields("COLUMN_NAME").Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend

        For i = 1 To dictColumns.Count
            Debug.Print dictColumns.Item(i)
        Next i
```

You can find details of all of the fields returned in the COLUMNS rowset [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723052%28v%3dvs.85%29). For Excel, however, it is likely that some of those fields will contain Null because they relate to features which Excel does not support

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the first column of the SQL query like this:

```
dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
...
...
...
id = rs.Fields(0)
```

ps Notice how I use **Early Binding** by referencing the ADODB DLL. This is a better method than **Late Binding** as you get intellisense.

Comment: Both great answers, barrowc's answer fit my needs better.